# Creating a select query based on selected checkboxes in asp.net in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I've two tables in the database named Customer and orders. In my ASP.NET page I've checkboxes representing the the fields in those two tables. [image]

The user can select from the checkboxes (Firstname,OrderitemName is compulsory). Based on the selected checkboxes,  I need to generate a sql query. The query will be returning the results with filter applied from the CustomerType Drop down list when the user presses Submit button.

For this, I checked whether the checkbox is selected in my code and passed it as bit type in my stored procedure. My stored procedure is,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomerDetails]     
@LastName BIT,
@Phone BIT,
@Email BIT,
@Quantity BIT,
@OrderedDate BIT,
@ReturnPolicy BIT,
@CustomerType nvarchar(40)
```

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELCARE 
        @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)

```
SET @Sql='SELECT c.FirstName,o.OrderItemName'
IF @LastName =1
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@sql+'c.LastName,'
    END 
IF @Phone =1
    BEGIN
         SET @Sql=@sql+'c.Phone,'
    END 
IF @Email =1
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@sql+'c.Email,'
    END
IF @Quantity =1
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@sql+'o.Quantity,'
    END 
IF @OrderDate =1
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@sql+'o.OrderDate,'
    END 
IF @ReturnPolicy =1
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@sql+'o.ReturnPolicy'
    END

SET @sql=@sql +' ' +'from Customer c inner join Order o on c.CustomerId=o.CustomerID where c.CustomerType =' + '@CustomerType'

EXEC(@sql)
```

END

Right now, many additional table columns (30 columns) had been added in the checkbox in the asp.net page. This is just adding too many bit type variables and if conditions to check those bit type variable and concatenate it to @sql based on those bit type variable in the stored procedure. Is there any better way to accomplish this? Please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you write up Inline queries in such cases.. You can just iterate thru the checkbox lists and create the query in the for loop itself

Comment: Since you are not using those checked fields in where clause, why didn't you select all columns from database and only show those fields that matched checked?

Comment: @ codingbiz, I thought of your approach also. In above example, I'm showing just one dropdownlist for filter (where condition) but my actual has 5 or 6 of them. Anyway, your idea seems to provide faster solution to my issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First create a table, lets call it filters having 3 columns as follows:

```
1. filter varchar(100)
2. inputBit bit
3. condition (this can be any condition, may be date time or any incremental int)
```

now insert your filter conditions along with input bits for all the columns: This would look like as follows:

```
c.LastName  1 11
c.Phone 1 11
c.Email 1 11
o.Quantity  1 11
o.OrderDate 1 11
o.ReturnPolicy  1 11
```

In above example, i have considered the condition to be int, and its value for a particular instance is 11, for next instance it can be something else.

now use the following query:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)
declare @var1 varchar(100)
declare @var2 bit
SET @Sql='SELECT c.FirstName,o.OrderItemName'
declare cur_filtered_view cursor for
select filter,inputBit from filters where condition = 11
open cur_filtered_view
fetch next from cur_filtered_view into @var1,@var2
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
if(@var2 = 1)
begin
    set @Sql = @Sql+','+@var1
end
fetch next from cur_filtered_view into @var1,@var2
end
close cur_filtered_view
deallocate cur_filtered_view
set @Sql = @Sql + ' from Customer c inner join Order o on c.CustomerId=o.CustomerID where c.CustomerType =' + '@CustomerType' 
exec (@Sql)
```

Now, if there are any new filters to be added, you will have to pass it as bits from front end to Proc anyways. The only updates that will be required thereafter is to add a row for those new filters in the filters table and on each proc call insert the relevant values in filters table.

Comment: Thanks Seasoned. I'll try your approach as well.